# Magento update skus (mysql query)

Tags: magento

I need to update all **configurable** products skus, set "-1" in the end. I do not know stucture of magento database, so if anybody can help with  query, or which tables have info about skus and type of products. 
tnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
UPDATE 
    `catalog_product_entity` 
SET 
    `sku` = CONCAT (`sku`, '-1') 
WHERE 
    `type_id` = 'configurable';
```

You may need to rebuild your indexes when you are done. Also back-up first your db in case I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to update "sku" using Marius answer but all of updated products stop showing in PLP and search result. So here are the all queries I have used to resolve this issue.

```
UPDATE `shared_catalog_product_item` SET sku = CONCAT('ZX-', sku);
UPDATE `sales_order_item` SET sku = CONCAT('ZX-', sku);
UPDATE `quote_item` SET sku = CONCAT('ZX-', sku);
```

The reason was if you are updating sku from 'catalog_product_entity', you have to update in other tables as well if you application is fully functionality and there is already placed order against that sku.
Hope this help to other as well.